# Why does adding "where id" to a mysql query return zero results?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

This query correctly returns 3 orders, one of which has an id of 12.

```
select * from `orders` where `is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `partner_id` = '2')
```

And if I want to query for just that order, I would add where id = 12, so I do:

```
select * from `orders` where `is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `partner_id` = '2') and `orders`.`id` = '12'
```

And now it returns zero results. Am I taking crazy pills? I don't see anything wrong with my syntax, all of the columns are explicitly referring to the correct table, etc.

In case it helps, this is being automatically generated by Laravel. Here's the laravel code:

This returns 3 results:

```
$order = Order::completed()
    ->whereHas('orderPayments', function ($query) use ($partner) {
        $query->where('partner_id', $partner->id);
    })->get();
```

This returns none:

```
$order = Order::completed()
    ->whereHas('orderPayments', function ($query) use ($partner) {
        $query->where('partner_id', $partner->id);
    })->where('id', 12)->first();
```

Edit:

For clarification, this query correctly returns the order.

```
select * from `orders` where `is_completed` = '1' and `orders`.`id` = '12'
```

Doing a `where id = 12` returns the correct result, as does the `exists`, but not together. Doing both returns nothing while both return the correct result if done separately. That's what doesn't make sense.

Edit: the orders table describe:

```
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id                | int(11)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| is_completed           | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| created_at             | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at             | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And the order_payments table:

```
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| order_id                   | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| partner_id                 | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| amount_in_pennies          | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at                 | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at                 | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And here's the query results from the first query:

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | is_completed | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  6 |       1 |            1 | 2017-05-20 18:04:08 | 2017-05-24 17:35:37 |
| 11 |       1 |            1 | 2017-05-24 22:54:56 | 2017-05-24 22:55:28 |
| 12 |       1 |            1 | 2017-05-24 23:12:09 | 2017-05-24 23:12:38 |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And the results from the order_payments table:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | order_id | partner_id |
+----+----------+------------+
|  7 |        6 |          2 |
| 12 |       11 |          2 |
| 14 |       12 |          2 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

And, just to make things spicier, this query does work and returns the result successfully:

```
select * from `orders` where `orders`.`is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `order_payments`.`partner_id` = '2') and `id` = '6';
```

So order ID 6 works, 11 doesn't, and 12 doesn't.

Here's the full contents of the order_payments table:

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | order_id | partner_id |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |        1 |          1 |
|  2 |        2 |          1 |
|  3 |        3 |          1 |
|  4 |        4 |          1 |
|  5 |        5 |          1 |
|  6 |        6 |          1 |
|  7 |        6 |          2 |
|  8 |        7 |          1 |
|  9 |        8 |          1 |
| 10 |        9 |          1 |
| 11 |       10 |          1 |
| 12 |       11 |          2 |
| 13 |       11 |          1 |
| 14 |       12 |          2 |
| 15 |       12 |          1 |
+----+----------+------------+
```

The only thing I can think of is perhaps this is a mysql bug, and it's somehow matching the order_payments id of 6 which matches the order id of 6 since it's the only occurance where the order_payments id and the orders id match. Is this a mysql bug or do I need to alias differently?

And, to make things even more super duper spicy, here's some more funky query results:

1 result:

```
select * from `orders` where `orders`.`is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `order_payments`.`partner_id` = '2') and `id` = '6';
```

0 results:

```
select * from `orders` where `orders`.`is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `order_payments`.`partner_id` = '2') and `id` = '11';
```

0 results:

```
select * from `orders` where `orders`.`is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `order_payments`.`partner_id` = '2') and `id` = '12';
```

Now, the same queries but with the partner_id changed from 2 to 1:

1 result:

```
select * from `orders` where `orders`.`is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `order_payments`.`partner_id` = '1') and `id` = '6';
```

1 result:

```
select * from `orders` where `orders`.`is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `order_payments`.`partner_id` = '1') and `id` = '11';
```

1 result:

```
select * from `orders` where `orders`.`is_completed` = '1' and exists (select * from `order_payments` where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` and `order_payments`.`partner_id` = '1') and `id` = '12';
```

These should be returning a valid result since a payment exists to both partners for all three of those orders. Funky stuff!

Comment: is orderID is varchar or int?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu yes, but that's not the issue. I edited my post to include another query that works, without the exists clause but with the id.

Comment: In Laravel, `->get()` returns a collection, `->first()` returns an element. Are you sure you're treating the result variable `$order` appropriately in your second query?

Comment: @e_i_pi They're not being run sequentially. If I run those two queries manually against the database in command line it still returns those results. The ->get() vs ->first() is for testing.

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` definition for the `orders` table please?

Comment: @e_i_pi I updated my post to include it.

Comment: I'm about to go to lunch, but could I be a pain and ask you to post the query result of the first query?

Comment: @e_i_pi Yes, I updated the post to include the results.

Comment: Does the subquery return the expected result if you fix the order.id to 12?

Comment: can you post the data in the payment table?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Yes, added.

Comment: @Citizen , question do you really need to use exists? because you can just use an inner join to show if there's a match.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu it could be a 1--to-many join, which would then return duplicate results.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu This is the query that Laravel generates with proper eloquent relationships.

Comment: @e_i_pi Yes, it is a one to many result.

Comment: Just to discard it: Is it the same if you put "and order.id = 12" before the exists clause instead of after it?

Comment: @Juan Yup, also returns zero results.

Comment: i think that's a mysql bug, just did the same query structure to sql-server and works fine

Comment: do you use eloquent relationship ?

Comment: @Demonyowh Yes, orders have many orderPayments

Comment: what does completed() method do ?

Comment: Just to point out that the record where the 2 ids are 6 has partner_id 1 which should be excluded by the subquery. So the result should still correspond to the other record with id 7.

Comment: correct me if im wrong .. what you're trying to achieve is get an specific order and a specific order payment using the partner id ?

Comment: @Demonyowh isCompleted() is a query scope that adds the is_completed = 1 clause. The desired result is a specific order but only if completed and with at least one payment to the specified partner.

Comment: What about changing the * in the subquery by a 1. (select 1 from ..)

Comment: @Juan That worked! WHY??? Changing * to id works, using order_id does not...

Comment: I still would go with the bug theory.

Comment: @Juan How on earth did you guess the solution? It 100% works.

Comment: Just troubbleshooting, try and error, and look for different ways in which the query could get resolved by the DBMS.

Comment: @Juan Please post this as an answer and I'll accept as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After troubbleshooting the problem, the solution for mysql to deliver the correct results for the query was achieved by re-writting the subquery replacing the star (*) for 'id' in the select of the subquery.

```
select * 
from `orders` 
where `is_completed` = '1' 
and exists (
        select `id` 
        from `order_payments` 
        where `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id` 
        and `partner_id` = '2'
) 
and `orders`.`id` = '12'
```

Even if this resolved the problem, I still think it is a bug in mysql, that prevented the original query to deliver the correct result.